# Iterating through Array Object to display multiple images

Tags: firebase, react-native, object, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to iterate through all the "url" in the "photo" array and display it on the feed page of my react native app. This is how I am doing it in the flatlist:

```
                    <View>
                    {
                      (item.photo).map(photoItem => (
                        <Image 
                          source={{ uri: photoItem.url }}
                        />
                      )) 
                    }
                    </View>
```

The object looks like this:

```
photo_feed is:  Array [
  Object {
    "author": "Jack",
    "authorId": "edm9AAbPpFUWrO9HDXfV442QzSE2",
    "caption": "Test 1",
    "id": "55a3-ba48-6709-ccf4-3338",
    "posted": "29 minutes ago",
    "url": Array [
      Object {
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...some url...",
      },
      Object {
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...some url...",
      },
      Object {
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...some url...",
      },
    ],
    "vote": 0,
  },
]
```

I am able to grab the value but am not able to iterate through it and show all the images on the screen at once.

I am getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: photoItem
```

Here is the full flatlist:

```
          <FlatList
            refreshing={this.state.refresh}
            onRefresh={this.loadNew}
            data={this.state.photo_feed}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#eee", flex: 1 }}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <View key={index} style={styles.flatlistImage}>
                <View style={styles.postDetails}>
                  <Text>{item.posted}</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <View>
                    {
                      (item.photo).map(photoItem => (
                        <Image 
                          source={{ uri: photoItem.url }}
                          style={styles.profilephoto} 
                        />
                      )) 
                    }
                    </View>
                </View>
              </View>

            )}
          />
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it should be item.url instead of item.photo, because your object is named like this.